# Use array to add more than one type, multiple times

Tags: java, arrays

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package demo;

/**
 *
 * @author mikel
 */
public class Individual {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String phone;
    private String mail;
    private String afm;
    private int icode;
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int grade;
    private int i=1;


    /*----------get-----------*/
        public String getName()
        {
            return this.name;
        }

        public String getSurname()
        {
            return this.surname;
        }

        public String getPhone()
        {
            return this.phone;
        }
        public String getMail()
        {
            return this.mail;
        }
        public String getAfm()
        {
            return this.afm;
        }
        public int getiCode()
        {
            return this.icode;
        }
        public int getYear()
        {
            return this.year;
        }
        public int getMonth()
        {
            return this.month;
        }
        public int getDay()
        {
            return this.day;
        }
        public int getGrade()
        {
            return this.grade;
        }
    /*----------set-----------*/    

        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setSurname(String surname)
        {
            this.surname = surname;
        }

        public void setPhone(String phone)
        {
            this.phone = phone;
        }

        public void setAfm(String afm)
        {
            this.afm = afm;
        }

        public void setiCode(int icode)
        {
            this.icode = icode;
        }

        public void setYear(int year)
        {
            this.year = year;
        }

        public void setMonth(int month)
        {
            this.month = month;
        }

        public void setDay(int day)
        {
            this.day = day;
        }

        public void setGrade(int grade)
        {
            this.grade = grade;
        }
```

I'm learning Java right now, and I had a question, I need to add information for more than one person in an array, but in this array I would like to have more than one type of info.
What I mean:

```
John Smith 964564 email@gg.com 564789

Mikel Nan  589456 email@gg.com 123123
```

So the result looks like an array.

My project asks the program to be able to print on screen a list of all names and info of people that I add.

Using this as a solution, that I saw in an other answer I don't get the expected result.

```
Object[] obj = new Object[]{name, surname, phone, mail, afm};
```

Also I want to add more than one person in this list, so in that way I have to make more objects or there is another way?

Thank you in advance for your time!
Sorry if my explanation isn't so clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Mikel its better to use ArrayList of `Individual` class objects for this purpose.

Then use for each loop or iterator over the list and display every object from `ArrayList`.

Put a constructor like this in your `Individual` class

```
public Individual(String name, String surname, String phone,
    String mail, String afm, int icode, int year, int month, int day,
    int grade) {


    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.mail = mail;
    this.afm = afm;
    this.icode = icode;
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
    this.grade = grade;

}
```

Add every Individual person info by using this.

Declare an `ArrayList` Like thiis

```
ArrayList<Individual> individualInfo = new ArrayList<Individual>();
```

Every time when you want to add an new person info you can add like these

```
individualInfo.add(new Individual(name, surname, phone, mail, afm, icode, year, month, day, grade));
```

when you want to iterate over the `individualInfo ArrayList` use for each loop like this.

```
  for (Individual individual: individualInfo) {

      //individual.getName();
      // Like these you can get the properties of individual objects.
  }
```

You can also use Iterator for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll search for some tutorials for ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use List then you can simply add using method .add(new Individual()

Answer (score 0):

You need a constructor:

```
Individual []individuals = new Individual[] {
    new Individual(name1, surname1, phone1, mail1, afm1),
    new Individual(name2, surname2, phone2, mail2, afm2),
    new Individual(name3, surname3, phone3, mail3, afm3)
};
```

Add it to a list with:

```
ArrayList<Individual> listIndividuals = new ArrayList<Individual>(
    Arrays.asList(individuals)
    );
```